# tooltip / lightning helptext appears in wrong location, misaligned

Tags: lightning-web-components, helptext, tooltip

I have a fairly simple template:

```html
<template>
    <div>
        Some text here
        <lightning-helptext content="I am incorrectly aligned"></lightning-helptext>
    </div>
</template>
```

When I hover over this tooltip in my sandbox, it's put in the wrong place:

[image: screenshot showing tooltip is about 300px to the left of where it's supposed to be]

I'm unable to reproduce this in a LWC playground, so I suspect this LWC bug is related either to an ancestor element, or this element's position on the page, or the fact that this is in the right column of a 2 column layout.

If I remove the text, the tooltip shows up in the "correct" place:

```html
<template>
    <div>
        <lightning-helptext content="I am incorrectly aligned"></lightning-helptext>
    </div>
</template>
```

[image: no text tooltip showing correct alignment]

Any idea what could be causing this LWC bug? I know there's not enough information to reproduce, I'm both unable to craft a setup in my sandbox that fixes it, nor am I able to craft a playground example that reproduces it.

I have also discovered that this bug affects standard edit forms with tooltips (this isn't a LWC, it's a standard Salesforce record view form):

[image: incorrect tooltip on standard record edit form]

Comment: is there more to the styling in your LWC that leads to the incorrect screenshot? Does inspecting the page lead to anything interesting?

Comment: After some additional investigation, this is affecting multiple tooltips across our app, including standard record edit forms. This is likely a Salesforce bug

Comment: I used the code above and it works fine. Did you try with some other browser or in some other resolution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is/was a Salesforce UI bug. Salesforce has notoriously poor release processes. There was recently [a full outage](https://issues.salesforce.com/issue/a028c00000pZ8BHAA0/help-text-on-the-fields-is-getting-frozen-even-after-hovering-outside-of-the-text) ([related question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/396358/hover-issue-in-salesforce)) where tooltips got stuck open. It took almost a week to fix.

Misaligned tooltips are not due to your own code, they are due to Salesforce's buggy UI framework. There is no known fix you can implement for them, other than waiting for Salesforce to fix it.

Since this ticket, and the later full outage, we have not seen this issue come up again.