# Hover issue in salesforce

Tags: apex, community, case, tooltip

In salesforce case, every time I hover my mouse over to "i" symbol(information symbol), the popups stay on screen even after removing the mouse and it wont disappear. It prevents me from clicking the button underneath it.

Is it a GUI glitch ? Or anything else?

Thanks for your help!

Regards,
Vikas Rahar

Comment: This is a critical bug in Salesforce latest release. Please file a ticket with Salesforce to help raise this to them.

Comment: https://issues.salesforce.com/issue/a028c00000pZ8BHAA0/help-text-on-the-fields-is-getting-frozen-even-after-hovering-outside-of-the-text

Answer (score 0):

This is/was a Salesforce UI bug. Salesforce has notoriously poor release processes. It was
[a full outage](https://issues.salesforce.com/issue/a028c00000pZ8BHAA0/help-text-on-the-fields-is-getting-frozen-even-after-hovering-outside-of-the-text) where tooltips got stuck open. It took almost a week to fix.